# 'C' programming - arcane struct syntax - almost looks like a python dictionary - What is this?

Tags: c, arrays, data-structures, client-server, command-line-arguments

I am fairly new to 'C' and have run into an expression that has me totally baffled.

```
static struct option gLongOption[] = {
{"port", arg, NULL, 'p'},
{"maxqueue", arg, NULL, 'q'},
{"help", non_arg, NULL, 'h'},
{NULL, 0, NULL, 0}}
```

What is this?
Why is an array being declared as a structure? Why is the array-stucture being assigned (what looks like) other structures? Is this a standard practice in C that has a name and I can go read about? Is this 'C' way of creating "dictionary" structures? The two thing I know is that above is related to command line arguments found in argv intended as input for a client\server model; otherwise, I am thoroughly confused. Thank you for the assistance.

Comment: Look up aggregate initialization. http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/struct_initialization

Answer (score 4):

`gLongOption` is an array of structs.
C allows to initialize an array like so:

```
int array[] = {1, 2, 3}:
```

Taking this further, in recent C dialects you can even later on change the array content by:

```
int array = {0};
...
array = (int[]) {1, 2, 3};
```

Similarily, you can initialize structs like so:

```
struct my_struct_t {
    int i;
    char c;
};

struct my_struct_t m = {1, 'a'};
```

`gLongOption` now is an array of structs, thus

```
static struct option gLongOption[] =
{ 
    {"port", arg, NULL, 'p'},   // initialize  gLongOption[0] as a struct of type struct option 
    {"maxqueue", arg, NULL, 'q'},  // initialize gLongOption[1]
    {"help", non_arg, NULL, 'h'},  // etc.
    {NULL, 0, NULL, 0}
};
```

initializes an array, whose elements happen to be structs, thus the elements are initialized as structs.

Just for the sake of completeness, you can also use the names of the elements of a struct to assign the entire struct a new value, e.g.

```
m = (struct my_struct_t){
    .i = 2,  // note the dot. The comma could be ommitted
};
```

All elements which are not explicitly initialized are then initialized with zeros, thus `m.c == '\0'` after the assignment above.

Comment: I thought it looked like a list (array) of struct type; however, I did not know that C allowed such things to go on. Certainly this can be done in Python.  I thought the syntax, arry[ ] was basically short hand for, char* arry, so that the only arrays possible were string arrays.

Comment: @H3G3moKnight Not quite: c arrays are arrays, not pointers, which can be seen by e.g: `int* i; int a[10]; printf("%zu %zu" sizeof(i), sizeof(a))`. However, arrays are under the hood represented  as pointers to the first element, and they are often implicitly cast to pointers, e.g. when handed over as function argument: `void f(int a[])` and `void f(int* a)` are equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

It is nothing like a python dictionary, that uses a hashing algorithm on a key to find a value, this is just an array of structs (not an array declared as a struct).

It looks like it comes from [GNU `getopt_long`](http://It%20is%20nothing%20like%20a%20python%20dictionary,%20that%20uses%20a%20hashing%20algorithm%20on%20a%20key%20to%20find%20a%20value,%20this%20is%20just%20an%20array%20of%20structs%20(not%20an%20array%20declared%20as%20a%20struct).%20It%20looks%20like%20it%20comes%20from%20GNU%20getopt_long,%20you%20should%20read%20the%20documentation%20to%20understand%20the%20fields.%20It%20is%20by%20no%20means%20unusual.%20gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Getopt-Long-Options.html), you should read the documentation to understand the fields. It is by no means unusual.

```
static struct option gLongOption[]
```

To read this declaration you can use the rule, "look right, keep looking, then look left".

First find the variable name `gLongOption`, then look right.  When we see `[]` we say "array of".  So `gLongOption` is an array of .....

Nothing else to the right, so look left, `struct option`, and is `static`.

So `gLongOption` is an array of struct options, and is `static`.

This simple method breaks down a little when we have embedded parentheses, so we have to use the rules of precedence, you should look at that later.

The `{"port", arg, NULL, 'p'}` and so on is just a way of initialising a struct, the elements are given in order.